# Is the sentence "The story that excites." grammatical and usable?

Tags: transitive-verbs

Technically "excite" is a transitive verb and therefore should be followed by an object. However, I have seen other examples following similar structures as such:

> The little engine that could.

or

> The ties that bind.

Could it be an idiomatic expression that follows a **Subject + that + Verb** model? And if that's the case, does it apply to every verb?

Comment: It's actually [the **ties** that bind](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ties+that+bind).

Comment: It's not a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

All of your examples are noun phrases, not sentences. To be a sentence, the noun phrase requires a main verb:

> The brakes that bind **are** the green ones.
> This book by Arthur Ransome **is** the story that excites.

With that proviso...

*That* in these sentences or your phrases is a relative pronoun, referring to the main noun, *story, engine, tires, ties, brakes.* Any action which the main noun can do can follow *that.*

> This story excites [people]. It is *the story that excites.*

Comment: "The story that excites" is not a sentence.  But it is fine to use as a title, for example.  Titles need not be sentences.

Comment: Yes, or an advertising slogan or tagline.

Answer (score 0):

> Technically, "excite" is a transitive verb

No. Technically, "excite" is an **ambitransitive** verb, i.e. if a direct object is not stated, it can be implied.

"The stories do excite [the reader] but not in a good way."

> The little engine that could.

There is an implication here of "do what was required because of determination." (It is a title and titles should never be taken as perfect examples.)

> The ties that bind.

again this is ambitransitive. The generally implied object is "people".

Also "Put some glue on it, and it will bind."